# Access Browser LocalStorage by Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am trying to access browser localstorage by a winform C# application and found out that Microsoft.Data.SQLite library can do that. But it looks like that this library is for .net core, not for full .net framework.

What is the equivalent library of it for full .net framework? Or is there any other way to access the browser localstorage from within a winform application?

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so search for & install System.Data.SQLite in the Visual Studio package manager (NuGet in the tools menu).  You can do the same for Microsoft.Data.SQLite which is not .Net Core only, but IMO the former is superior.

Comment: Thank Alex. Yes, I am using VS.net 2017 and will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the package to your winforms application using the NuGet console.

To open the console:
http://prntscr.com/nyxtva (Sorry for german language)

Then enter the following command: `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.110`

For more informations take a look at this NuGet page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/